# Group by column name -> specific value in that column

Tags: php, sql, group-by, sum

I'm stuck on this query...

```
SELECT SUM(points) AS total FROM `library` AS lib JOIN subitem_lib AS subitem on lib.id = subitem.lid JOIN items AS item on subitem.iid = item.id group by item.pid
```

Is it possible to get a specific field value from the item.pid?
This column can have different values (1 -> 9999999...)

I got this page rendered with php where it gives me a project id (pid). Now, my count should get the points specific for that project.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `WHERE item.pid = yourpidvaluehere`?

Comment: Add `where item.pid = XXX` ?

Comment: Yes indeed.. that was a dumb question tbh. Thanks for help though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add where condition in your query to restrict the result to specific